# decodeStream is always null in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, ionic-framework, widget

I have an Ionic project. In this ionic project, I want to create widgets for Android and iOS. I create a QR code as soon as I log in to the application. I am trying to set this file as a widget image using Android Studio. But decodeStream always comes back null and the widget image also comes up empty. What could be the problem?

My example code:

```
final File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx.yyy/files/zzz.png");
        //Log.d(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().exists())
      Log.d("STATE", "updateAppWidgettttttttttttttttt: "+file.exists());
      Log.d("STATE", "sdasdasdasdasd: "+file.length());

        // Construct the RemoteViews object
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.xy);
      AtomicFile atomicFile =  new AtomicFile(file);
      FileOutputStream fos = null;
      try {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        fos = atomicFile.startWrite();
        Log.d("showmethebitmap", bitmap.toString());
        OutputStream oos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,0,oos);
        oos.flush();
        atomicFile.finishWrite(fos);


        File location = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/Android/data/com.xxx.yyy/files/");
        File dest = new File(location, "zzz" + ".png");
        FileInputStream fis;
        fis = new FileInputStream(dest);
        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis); //bitmap alwasy null
        views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, img);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

      } catch (IOException e) {
        atomicFile.failWrite(fos);
        Log.d("TAG", "updateAppWidget: "+e);
      }
```